# LinearLayout inside ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

In this xml I am trying to display 7 ImageView and hence I am using a ScrollView. But, in the emulator it does not display the first ImageView fully. Only its lower half is getting displayed. How do I resolve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/homescreen_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_header"
            android:src="@drawable/logoheader" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empinfo_logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_emp_info"
            android:src="@drawable/employee_info" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leaveinfo_logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_info"
            android:src="@drawable/leave_info" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/holidays_logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_holidays"
            android:src="@drawable/holidays" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leavereq_logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_req"
            android:src="@drawable/leave_request" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leavestatus_logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_status"
            android:src="@drawable/leave_status" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logout_button"
            android:src="@drawable/logout" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: width is not fill parent of your first image and remove this line android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: Why the height of all images is fill_parent it should be wrap_content to adjust itself according to source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change android:layout_gravity = "center" to android:gravity="center" in LinearLayout and change the width and height of all ImageView to "wrap_content".

Comment: you saved my mind. but, can you explain the difference between layout_gravity and gravity ?

Answer (score 1):

Height of your Linear layout should be match parent and the Width and height of your images must be wrap content. This may help you.

Comment: If not width atleast the height.

Answer (score 0):

use this code....

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/homescreen_bg">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_header"
        android:src="@drawable/logoheader" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/empinfo_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_emp_info"
        android:src="@drawable/employee_info" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leaveinfo_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_info"
        android:src="@drawable/leave_info" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/holidays_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_holidays"
        android:src="@drawable/holidays" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leavereq_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_req"
        android:src="@drawable/leave_request" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leavestatus_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Homescreen_leave_status"
        android:src="@drawable/leave_status" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logout_button"
        android:src="@drawable/logout" />
</LinearLayout>
```